# Pandas or R - Merge Rows By Same Value in Column Over NaN values - Look at Example

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a very specific dataset it looks something like this:

| record_id | event_id | instrument | repeat_inst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PI0005 | v03_abc_1 | `NaN` | 1 |
| PI0005 | v03_abc_1 | i_sensor | `NaN` |
| PI0005 | v03_abc_1 | `NaN` | `NaN` |
| PI0005 | v02_abc_33 | i_sensor | `NaN` |
| PI0005 | v02_abc_33 | `NaN` | `NaN` |
| PI0006 | v02_abc_1 | i_sensor | 1 |
| PI0006 | v02_abc_1 | `NaN` | `NaN` |

How do I make it look like this:

| record_id | event_id | instrument | repeat_inst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PI0005 | v03_abc_1 | i_sensor | 1 |
| PI0005 | v02_abc_33 | i_sensor | `NaN` |
| PI0006 | v02_abc_2 | i_sensor | 1 |

Where rows with the same `record_id` and `event_id` get merged together, where `NaN` values are replaced with the other value, and if both values are `NaN`, then `NaN` can be kept (like in the forth and fifth row in the original dataframe).

Assume that only one of the related cells have a value and all others have `NaN`.

This should apply to all columns of the data, there are thousands of columns and rows.

I tried using group by, but don't know how to continue.

Comment: pandas: `df.groupby(['record_id', 'event_id'], as_index=False).first()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `R`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(record_id, event_id) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(),  ~.x[!is.na(.x)][1]))
```